# the image of NSTextAttachment is flipped

Tags: objective-c, nstextattachment

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"emotion"];;
attachment.image = image;
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString  attributedStringWithAttachment: attachment];
[[_feedbackContent textStorage] appendAttributedString:attributedString];
```

after add the image to NSTextAttachment, it is vertical flipped. Anybody know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [Images being flipped when adding to NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666322/images-being-flipped-when-adding-to-nsattributedstring)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images being flipped when adding to NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666322/images-being-flipped-when-adding-to-nsattributedstring)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

NSTextAttachment seems to use NSFileWrapper filename to get the UTI  and has different behaviour based on the UTI.

I was able to fix it with using NSFileWrapper instead:

```
NSFileWrapper *fileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:data];
// Without a filename (which is used to get the UTI by NSTextAttachment)
// the image is displayed flipped.
[fileWrapper setPreferredFilename:@"Attachment.png"];
NSTextAttachment  *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithFileWrapper:fileWrapper];
```

You could also try to set the `fileType` property to `kUTTypePNG` or other image type to get it working.

radar://47170950

Answer (score 3):

Assign the image to an NSTextAttachmentCell, not the NSTextAttachment.

```
id <NSTextAttachmentCell> cell = [[NSTextAttachmentCell alloc] initImageCell:image];

NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:nil];
[attachment setAttachmentCell:cell];
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer works best for me. I did previously draw the image flipped, but that causes issues with cut and copy operations. One side effect of this approach is that setting the `bounds` property of `NSTextAttachment` does no longer resize the image. I have to change the `size` of `NSImage` directly.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing into a flipped view (which is why the image gets flipped), the only workaround I've found is to create a flipped image so it's then drawn the :

```
textAttachment.image = [NSImage imageWithSize:image.size flipped:YES drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {
    [image drawInRect:dstRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    return YES;
}];
```